# Changing record values based on whether there are duplicates when two tables are combined

Tags: sql

I know I can join `Table #1` and `Table #2` with a `UNION` and then filter out duplicate `Id`'s using `DISTINCT`. However, for the duplicate contacts I'd like to change `DrinkPreference` to `Coke/Pepsi`.

Is this possible?

Starting `Table #1`

| Id | FirstName | LastName | DrinkPreference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Tom | Bannon | Pepsi |
| 124 | Sarah | Smith | Pepsi |

Starting `Table #2`

| id | FirstName | LastName | DrinkPreference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | Jim | Henry | Coke |
| 123 | Tom | Bannon | Coke |

`Table? #3`  - combined with `DrinkPreference` set to `Coke/Pepsi` where contact exists in both tables?

| Id | FirstName | LastName | DrinkPreference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | Jim | Henry | Coke |
| 123 | Tom | Bannon | Coke/Pepsi |
| 124 | Sarah | Smith | Pepsi |

Comment: Is ID in Firstname in Table 2?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.firstname, t2.firstname) AS firstname,coalesce(t1.lastname,t2.lastname) AS lastname, CASE WHEN t1.drinkpreferences IS NULL THEN  t2.drinkpreferences  WHEN t2.drinkpreferences IS NULL THEN  t1.drinkpreferences
 ELSE  t1.drinkpreferences || '/' || t2.drinkpreferences END AS drinkpreferences FROM table1 t1  FULL JOIN table2 t2   ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks, this way worked for me with using `concat()` instead of `t1.drinkpreferences || '/' || t2.drinkpreferences`.

Comment: one correction, the join should be on to table2.

Comment: yes, thanks. it is a spelling error. I have just edited

Answer (score 1):

Achievable using multiple `unions` and `joins`.

```
select distinct FirstName, LastName, case when ct = 2 then 'Coke/Pepsi' else DrinkPreference end
from (
    select FirstName, LastName, DrinkPreference, Id from table1
    union all
    select FirstName, LastName, DrinkPreference, Id from table2) a 
left join
(
    select count(1)ct, Id from
        (select Id from table1
        union all
        select Id from table2) t1
    group by Id
    ) b on b.Id = a.Id
```